# How to hide "Joe Bloggs liked this."-type posts on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, customization

Nowadays many of the Facebook posts I see are of this form:

```
Somebody I. Know liked this.
____________________________________

A story about a little girl living in New York.
Including photo.
1234567 likes 23456789 comments 3456789123 shares
```

I rather not see these posts, because when a friend *likes* something, this isn't as strong enough as them sharing it. In fact, if they don't *share* it on purpose, I take it to mean that they don't intend to share it. I suppose they don't like it enough to share it. I'd rather see messages they actually type in, photos they take, and links they share. And nothing more.

Is it possible to selectively hide these posts?

I use Firefox, but could switch to Chrome if there is a Chrome-only solution.

Answer (score 5):

First, add your friends to friend lists if they are not already in lists.  Click on Friends in the left sidebar to see your friend lists or create new lists.  For each list where you do not want to see certain types of updates, click on the name of the list (in the left sidebar or on the list page that comes up when you click Friends in the left sidebar), and then click on the Manage List button on the right.  Click on "Choose Update Types..." and then uncheck "Comments and Likes".

[image: Manage List » Choose Update Types...]
[image: Comments and Likes]

Comment: When I click on Manage List, I only get "rename, remove or edit" Edit does not give me options.

Comment: So I'd have to manually add people each time I accept or send a friend request?